# Trying to centralise a div inside another which is dynamic using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/dad4avvj/1/

Everytime I try to align it by doing `inline-block` and `text-align:center` it throws the numbers class out of position and looks wrong.

[image]

These circles are animated so they fill up over the course of a few seconds. I also need to add text under each one and equally pad them out within their container. Only problem is on the site I wish to implement it, it has a max-width of 900px;

How can I centralise this without messing up the rest of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `text-align: left;` to `.numbers` and  `text-align:center;` to `.bar` and remove `float:left` from  `.radial-progress` will solved your issue.

```
.numbers {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/dad4avvj/4/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good spot...and a quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

You also have `float:left` applied as well as `inline-block`.

If you remove that and apply `text-align:center` to the parent. it centers then just fine.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dad4avvj/2/)

```
#bar {

    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    height: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
   }

.radial-progress {
    display:inline-block;
   /* float:left; */
}
```

Comment: ^ The one on the left goes off screen and it flickers? http://jsfiddle.net/dad4avvj/3/